# Javascript magic number 79753741930607500

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any way to increase this number?

```
console.log(79753741930607500+1) // 79753741930607500
console.log(79753741930607499+3) // 79753741930607500
```

upd:

zip encrypt/decrypt functions use 64bit numbers:

```
keys[0] = 305419896;
keys[1] = 591751049;
keys[2] = 878082192;

this.update_keys=function(c){
    keys[0]=crc32.crc32(keys[0],c);
    keys[1]=(((keys[1]+(keys[0]&0xff))*0x08088405+1)& 0xffffffff) >>>0;
    keys[2] = crc32.crc32(keys[2], keys[1] >>> 24);
};
```

keys[1] intermediate calculation may be more 79753741930607500.

exists universal solution to nodejs and browsers can use 64bit integers?

Comment: @JanDvorak Why? Is this some sort of datatype upper limit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/307179/1169798

Comment: @LynnCrumbling yes. But the javavascript numeric data type has already been explained. OP should tell us what his actual question is if he wants it answered.

Comment: @Sirko console.log(Number.MAX_VALUE);
1.7976931348623157e+308

Comment: @askovpen There is a difference between `MAX_VALUE`, which is the biggest number you can use, and the number from my link, which is the largest integer, you can use without loss of precision.

Answer (score 3):

Since the question is tagged [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) this is possible using the [node-bigint](https://github.com/substack/node-bigint) module.

Install with

```
npm install bigint
```

Usage:

```
var bigint = require('bigint');

console.log(bigint('79753741930607500').add(3)); //<BigInt 79753741930607503>
```

Though do note, there's no way to keep it as an integer and it will be returned as a bigint string or you can convert it to a string with the method `.toString()`. If you do try and return it as an integer, you will lose precision or it will return infinity.

Comment: Is that a default module? Is there an official documentation for it?

Comment: @JanDvorak It's an external module, it's linked in the answer.

Comment: +1 Nice. Gives the OP an answer to their original question of how they can store and increment the number.

Comment: exists universal solution for nodejs and browsers?

Comment: If you'd taken any time to research, google would've brought you to [this](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum).

Comment: @BenFortune `javascript-bignum` don't have `bitwise and`

Comment: What are you talking about? Bitwise operators are a part of javascript.

Comment: @BenFortune for bigint. like https://github.com/substack/node-bigint#andn